# Extract data from outlook

Tags: uipath, uipath-robot

[image]

I've got many emails with the same format as shown in the screenshot above: **Finished Product**, **Material Description** and **Assembly Location**. Is there a way to extract specific data from an email? As seen from the screenshot above (the body of the email in outlook), I would like to get the result for Material Description; which in this case is `Nike` and paste over into an excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy. First the overlook:

[image: uipath process complete]

Now let's brake it down to the important parts so you can follow it way easy.

You need to following variables:

[image: variables]

The `Get Mail Messages` activity works best when you already have Outlook installed. If so take that:

[image: fetch mails]

In the `For Each` activity you set the Type to `MailMessage`

[image: Mail message]

In the `Regular expression` activity called `Matches` you go into the `item.Body` and matching all `Material Description: (.+)` occurrences.

[image: regex]

And finally you do anything you want with the found matches. Make sure to use another `for each` here if you have more than one match. If not it's the easiest way to access the occurrence with `Matches(0).toString` and before check if there is any match given:

[image: print]

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it out!!

Comment: yes. thank you! Sorry for the really late replies. Really appreciate it mate :)) Cheers!